# Unclosed Group near index using Regex

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to test a phone numbers format using regular expressions, regex, and when I run the Pattern.compile I receive the error **java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unclosed group near index 34**

```
public String checkPhoneNum(String inPhoneNum)
{
    Pattern checkRegex = Pattern.compile("(\\([0-9]{3}\\)([0-9]{3}(-)[0-9]{4})");
    Matcher regexMatcher = checkRegex.matcher(inPhoneNum);

    if(regexMatcher.find())
    {
        return inPhoneNum;
    }
    else
        return null;
}
```

is the string `(\\([0-9]{3}\\)([0-9]{3}(-)[0-9]{4})` not correctly written for format (000)111-2222?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are missing one closing parenthesis in the first matching group:

It should be

```
Pattern checkRegex = Pattern.compile("(\\([0-9]{3}\\))([0-9]{3}(-)[0-9]{4})");
```

As it is:

```
( - start of mathing group 
\\( - matches (  
[0-9]{3} - 3 digits  
\\) - matches )  
) - end of matching group (this is the one you missed)
```